# How to change deployment order in WebLogic?

Tags: deployment, weblogic, web-deployment, weblogic11g

According to this documentation it is possible to change deployment order in WebLogic:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/deployment/ChangeTheServerDeploymentOrder.html

For example I have two web applications **app1.war** and **app2.ear**.
I set "Deployment order" to 1 for app1.war.
And "Deployment order" 100 for app2.ear.
Does it mean that app1.war will be up and running prior WebLogic starting to launch app2.ear?

Unfortunately it does not work fo me. WebLogic starting to launch app1.war but then it starting to launch app2.ear when app1.war is not in STATE_ACTIVE yet.

Comment: Any idea how to set deployment order using offline create properties? Tried DeploymentOrder but it did not work and cannot seem to find this documented anywhere

Answer (score 5):

I think it will start and then complete the launching as per that order. I have tested on my server

It performs the following sequence.

One thread runs through all the apps in the deployment order and transitions all of them to PREPARED, then to ADMIN then to ACTIVE

In my example below, `dms.war` is set at 50 and `portletapp` is set at 100 as deployment order.

Thread 0 runs to make all to PREPARED and ADMIN

Thread 1 starts running to make them ACTIVE

```
####<04-Feb-2011 17:02:05 > <Info> <Deployer> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1296819125939> <BEA-149060> <Module dms.war of application DMS Application [Version=11.1.1.1.0] successfully transitioned from STATE_NEW to STATE_PREPARED on server DefaultServer.> 

####<04-Feb-2011 17:02:19 > <Info> <Deployer> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1296819139834> <BEA-149060> <Module portletapp of application wsrp-samples [Version=11.1.1.2.0] successfully transitioned from STATE_NEW to STATE_PREPARED on server DefaultServer.> 


####<04-Feb-2011 17:03:25 > <Info> <Deployer> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1296819205627> <BEA-149060> <Module dms.war of application DMS Application [Version=11.1.1.1.0] successfully transitioned from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server DefaultServer.>

####<04-Feb-2011 17:03:33 > <Info> <Deployer> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1296819213183> <BEA-149060> <Module portletapp of application wsrp-samples [Version=11.1.1.2.0] successfully transitioned from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server DefaultServer.> 

####<04-Feb-2011 17:04:57 > <Info> <Deployer> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <00e884cc3b492be0:-20717040:12df0741b5b:-8000-0000000000000006> <1296819297757> <BEA-149060> <Module dms.war of application DMS Application [Version=11.1.1.1.0] successfully transitioned from STATE_ADMIN to STATE_ACTIVE on server DefaultServer.>


####<04-Feb-2011 17:04:57 > <Info> <Deployer> <DefaultServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <00e884cc3b492be0:-20717040:12df0741b5b:-8000-0000000000000006> <1296819297767> <BEA-149060> <Module portletapp of application wsrp-samples [Version=11.1.1.2.0] successfully transitioned from STATE_ADMIN to STATE_ACTIVE on server DefaultServer.>
```

Comment: This works. But you cannot set the order in a deployment plan or a weblogic JEE descriptor. This is a pity, order is a property belonging to two applications, not to a server or a deployment.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, thread 1 puts two applications "**dms.war**" and "portletapp" to ACTIVE at the same time. If indeed the 2nd app depends on the 1st app, the 2nd app would fail. Maybe in your testing, it happens there is no such dependency?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already done so, in the Change Center of the Administration Console, click Lock & Edit (see Use the Change Center).
In the left pane of the Administration Console, select Deployments. The right pane displays all modules configured for deployment in the domain, listed in their current deployment order.

In the right pane, click the name of the module for which you want to change the deployment order.
In the Overview tab that displays, enter a new value in the Deployment Order field, and click Save to apply your changes.
To change the deployment order of a Startup class, follow the instructions in Configure startup classes.

To activate these changes, in the Change Center of the Administration Console, click Activate Changes. 
Not all changes take effect immediately—some require a restart (see Use the Change Center).